# Rocket’s height at a given time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A model rocket takes off from an elevated launch pad 9 feet above the ground. The rocket’s elevation follows the function $h =  -2t^2 + 12t + 9$, where $h$ represents the height after $t$ seconds. Which of the following ordered pairs $(t, h)$ could be the rocket’s height at a given time? Indicate all possible values.
>
> A. (1, 19)
> B. (2.5, 24.5)
> C. (3, 28)
> D. (4, 25)
> E. (5.5, 14.5)
> F. (6, 9)
> G. (7, 1)
> H. (7,10)

I checked for $h$, inputting values of $t$ in the given equation, and choose the right answers. Is there any other way, easier, smart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  You could write $h = 27 - 2(t-3)^2$ it may speed things up a bit and help you eliminate some choices.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the way is just to take each pair $(t,h)$ and check if it satisfies the given equation $h=-2t^2+12t+9$.